# How to load Different Partial Views on the same div by radio button selection?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

```
enter code here
*MainView.cshtml*: @RadioButtonFor(m=>m.registeras,Individual) @RadioButtonFor(m=>m.registeras,BusinessEntity) <div id="loadpartial"> </div>
```

I have a register form in which User can register as **Individual** or **Business** entity. I kept two radio buttons. 
If user selects Individual Radio Button, then that partial view should be loaded. if user selects Business entity radio Button then second partial view should be loaded  on the same div.
 I am new to asp.net mvc4 razor. Can someone **please give the sample code**.

Comment: you need to use ajax on radio button click event, show some effort what you tried

Comment: are you fimiliar with jquery ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use jQuery in order to make ajax calls.

First reference jQuery at the bottom of your page.

in your controller, define and implement a method which returns a partial view.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetRegisterForm(int registeras)
{
    if(registeras == Individual)
    {
        return PartialView("IndividualPartialViewName");
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("BusinessPartialViewName");
    }
}
```

Now in your view, you can call the above action using ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("[name=registeras]").on('change', function(){
            var $radio = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("GetRegisterForm", "ControllerName")',
                data: { registeras = $radio.val() }
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#loadpartial").html(data);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: actually data:{regesteredas:$radio.val()}} has worked. anyways thanks amila :)